# How should I fill a list with a combination of database entries and meta-values?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, data-binding, flex3

I am acquiring the contents of a table to fill a dropdown box in a Flex 3 application:

```
<mx:ComboBox dataSource="{myList}" />
```

The list is populated by the contents of a database table of persons:

```
Public, John Q
Doe, Jane
...
```

The combo box, however, also needs to have some other meta-entries in it that do not come from the database:

```
ALL
ALL MEN
ALL WOMEN
Public, John Q
Doe, Jane
...
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the setter for "mylist" and insert your values into the array.

```
public function set myList(value:Array):void {
  this._myList = ["ALL MEN", "ALL_WOMEN"].concat(value);
  this.dispatch(new FlexEvent(FlexEvent.DATA_CHANGE));
}
```

Comment: This seems a bit... clunky.  Also, when I need the values of myList for programmatic access in other situations this won't work.

Comment: Sure it will. You write a getter that returns _mylist and it contains the two new values. You can try to make it as elegant as you like, but it will be a variation on this. Maybe you want to override the combobox and insert these extra ones when someone assigns the dataprovider.

Comment: I did this in a slightly different place; the source field for my array collection performs this concatenation, since that's where the knowledge of the special handling lives.